# Can FlowType validate if a property is a DOM Object like HtmlDiv?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I keep a dom node on a object property, current I am using as a type `any` I would like to know if it is possible instead have a more specific type, example a type related to the DOM, in my example a div.

I cannot find proper reference in the documentation.

Any suggestions is welcome.

Comment: The entire list of supported types is here https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/#lib/dom.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a solution looking directly in their source code.

Type `HTMLDivElement` works for me.

Source:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js#L692